# @stomp/stomp.js: can I detect when a subscription was done successfully?

Tags: stompjs

I am using @stomp/stomp.js to connect to a Spring Boot service that allows websocket connections via STOMP. The spring boot service uses interceptors to check whether a user is allowed to subscribe to a topic or it should drop the subscription.

My implementation seems to be working fine (both client and server side) when a subscription is allowed on the server side, but on the client side I do not know if a subscription was successful until a message has been received. Is there some sort of callback/listener I can setup on a successful subscription?

Answer (score 0):

If using React on the client side, you can use it as follows:

1. Context

```js
const client = new SockJS(endPointUrl);
const stomp = Stomp.over(() => client);

// Turn off debug
// stomp.debug = () => {};

useEffect(() => {
  const connectToStomp = () => {
    stomp.connect({}, () => {});
  };

  connectToStomp();
}, [stomp]);
```

2. Use

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (stomp.connected) {
    stomp.subscribe('/your-endPoint', (res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
}, [stomp]);
```